# Fatal error after enabling backup and migrate module

Tags: debugging

I just enabled back up and migrate module. Then I backed up my site and tried to restore the site using the back up file and it did not allow me to do it.

Then when I go to admin > config > I get this error:

"One or more problems were detected with your Drupal installation. Check the status report for more information."

Then I go to admin > reports > status reports > click run cron manually > I get this error:

"
Fatal error: Class CToolsCssCache contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (DrupalCacheInterface::__construct) in /home/content/65/11722765/html/sites/all/modules/ctools/includes/css-cache.inc on line 52
"

Chaos tools 7.x-1.7

Drupal 7.22, 2013-04-03

Please advise,
 D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's about a bug in the ctools module. Please keep all discussion about bugs and their workarounds in the issue queues on Drupal.org. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2408217) and install the [ctools-cache-handler.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/ctools-cache-handler.patch) patch

Comment: Actually I never installed patch before. Could you please provide some steps? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1399218

Comment: The link that @FreeRadical gave you let you know how to install the patch

Comment: Is the patching only option? Is there other workaround?

Comment: It's about a bug in the ctools module so it is the only way